# Recursively copy files to remote server using expect script

Tags: expect

How can we copy the files recursively to the remote server using expect script or any other script?.

Constraints.
1. We couldn't limit the number of file will be copied.
2. File size may be 1mb or upto 10mb.

I was tried with the following script. But it's only transfer upto 4 or 5 files only. (I need to transfer files, nearly 200 or 300 above)

```
spawn scp -r /home/test root@example.com:/home/test
sleep 2
expect "password"
send "XXXXXX"
sleep 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the `spawn` command, add the line

```
set timeout -1
```

and replace the 2nd `sleep` command with

```
expect eof
```

Don't forget to add `\r` when you send your password:  `send "password\r"`

I'd recommend you set up SSH keys -- then you won't be prompted for a password and you don't need the expect script at all.

Comment: thanks @glenn. Your valuable answer is reduced my work. I have added the modified code for upcoming users.